# Convert custom date to mysql datetime

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a custom date format that I want to convert to `Datetime` so I can then insert into my database, I tried using `Datetime.ParseExact()` But I think I'm misunderstanding something as the code throws a `System.FormatException`.

I have the following date format from a csv

```
> 6/11/2014 9:00
```

and I wish to convert it to the mysql `datetime` format

```
> 0000-00-00 00:00:00 OR yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Notice they haven't included the seconds in the original date so I am unsure (without appending them to the end) how to set all records to just have "`00`" for seconds as it is not available.

I tried the following which throws an exception

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("6/11/2014 9:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: dont forget to upvote and accept if it works for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing you need to convert string to date time and than convert datetime tos tring

```
string strd = "6/11/2014 9:00";
DateTime dt ;
//convert datetime string to datetime
if(DateTime.TryParse(strd, out dt))
{
  //convert datetime to custom datetime format 
  Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", 
                   dt); ;
}
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late to answer that but I'm *really* surprised none of answer consider to use [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) to prevent a possible parsing error because of [`/` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) **or** considering your `string` is a standard date and time format for your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or not so you can or can't use [`DateTime.TryParse(string, out DateTime)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly.

First of all, let's look at what [`DateTime.ParseExact` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) says:

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.**

In your case, they don't match. You should use `d/MM/yyyy H:mm` format to parse your example string with a culture that have `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx). I *almost* always suggest to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this kind of situations;

```
string s = "6/11/2014 9:00";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d/MM/yyyy H:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    // result will be 2014-11-06 09:00:00
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know formats of your dates, then you can do this:

```
string stringDate = "6/11/2014 9:00";
//Your date formats of input
string[] dateFormats = new string[] 
{ 
    "d/MM/yyyy H:mm", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" 
    /* And other formats */ 
};

DateTime convertedDate;
bool isSuccessful = DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDate, dateFormats,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out convertedDate);

if (isSuccessful)
{
    //If conversion was successful then you can print your date at any format you like
    //because you have your date as DateTime object
    Console.WriteLine(convertedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")); /* Or other format you want to print */
}
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.